# Moment generating function - Can it be a polynomial?

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable such that P(X = 0) < 1.

Is it possible for a moment generating function of X to be a polynomial $a_n t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} +\cdots+  a_1 t +  a_0$? Why

Answer (score 0):

If the mgf $M_X(t)$ is a polynomial, the $2k$-th derivative of $M_X(t)$ is identically $0$ for some positive integer $k$. It follows that $E(X^{2k})=0$, which is only possible if $X$ is $0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: k is the degree of the polynomial? What about an infinite polynomial?

Comment: $2k$ is any integer greater than the degree of the polynomial. There is no such thing as an infinite polynomial.

Comment: My mistake. How about $... + a_n t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} +\cdots+  a_1 t +  a_0$?

Comment: A polynomial is an expression of the shape $a_0+a_1t+\cdots +a_nt^n$. It stops at some $n$.  So $1+t+t^2+t^3$ is a polynomial, but $1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots$ is not.

Comment: I did not say that that is a polynomial :)

Comment: If you mean can the mgf be an infinite series,  they all are.